# How to design a Sync Service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite, android-syncadapter, android-service-binding

We have the problem where we need to sync a lot of information periodically from our server in the background, and save it in our SQLite DB.

The way I see it, I have a few otpions, just not quite sure I fully understand all ramifications.

1) Have an in-process server with `START_STICK` being returned from `onStartCommand`, and addPeriodicSyncs (presumably on `Application#onCreate`).

2) Have an in-process server with `START_STICKY` which queues up timer tasks and periodically updates the database.

3) Have the `Service` run in its own process and write to our SQLite DB.

So, here are the questions:

a) Do options #1 and #2 preclude having a SyncAdapter? What is the benefit of running a SyncAdapter? (Outside of having to start a new `Thread` on the `Service` to make HTTP requests)

b) Do #1 and #2 survive my application being destroyed? If they do, do they bring back the entire application with them?

c) Can I write to my SQLite DB with #3? I'm guessing yes, since they would be under the same user ID right?

d) What's the easiest method to talk back and forth between #3 and the main application process? Broadcast receivers? Most of it would be handled by purely having `Cursor` with notification URIs

e) Just general thoughts, pros/cons, etc :)

Answer (score -1):

1. The main advantage of the Android sync framework is that you don't need to implement your own framework.
2. `addPeriodicSync()` writes sync settings to the system, means tells the Android sync framework to periodically run your sync adapter. So you don't need to implement your own scheduler. (You need to hold `WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS` permission)
3. Implement custom (not a stub) `ContentProvider` and perform CRUD on that. It's one of the main functions of Content Providers to manage inter-process communication, so you don't need broadcasts. Instead, use `ContentProvider` + `Loader` (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) to get cursors updated.

A content provider:

```
class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public Uri insert(...) {
        ...
        mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase.insert(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

A sync adapter:

```
class MySyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    public void onPerformSync(...) {
        ...
        new ContentResolver(getContext()).insert(...);
        ...
    }
}
```